# Relative path in PHPStorm for browserify

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, browserify, jetbrains-ide

My project is based on browserify requires. The IDE of choice is PHPStorm (should be the same for any other Jetbrains JS related product). And here is my code:

```
var Vue = require('../../libraries/vue-ajax.js');
var vmBoards = require('./boards.js');
```

I want those paths to be Ctrl-clickable (Ctrl+B for keyboard guys). Inability to do so really slows down development. Is it possible?

PHP storm somewhy resolves only "js" part of string:

[image: PHP storm somewhy resolves only "js" part of string]

Comment: PHPStorm resolves such paths relative to current file. If the referencved file can be found by specified relative path, Ctrl+click on file will work; otherwise no navigation is possible

Comment: @lena Those are real files. After all, browserify compiles just fine. No magic routing invlolved here. No symlinks as well.

Maybe something silly is missing in my IDE settings. Because route resolution works everywhere except for browserify. Even blade works.

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific settings. And files resolving in require() works fine for me, with or without browserify. Just an idea: do you have NodeJS plugin installed and enabled? paths resolving/completion in require() calls is controlled by it

Comment: @lena `do you have NodeJS plugin installed and enabled?`
That's it! You're awesome. Post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you have NodeJS plugin (`Settings | Plugins`, `Install JetBrains plugin...`, type 'NodeJS' to quickly locate it) installed and enabled - completion and paths resolving within `require()` calls is controlled by it